# How to set threads based on number of cores available?

Tags: snakemake

I have a workflow that runs on different machines with different numbers of CPUs, and I'd like to be able to setup a rule that uses "all but N" cores.  I.e. I'd like to be able to do:

`threads: lambda cores: max(2, cores-4)`

But I cannot find any way to access cores (i.e. the value passed to or inferred by -j/--cores on the commmand line) in my rules.  Is there a way to do the above?

Comment: Not sure this works from within snakemake, but just in case: `from multiprocessing import cpu_count`, and then use this to get the number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

As **@bli** said in the comments, this should work:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

rule test:
    output:
        example.txt
    threads: 
        lambda cores: max(2, cpu_count() - 4)
    shell:
        cmd -{threads}
```